# Spring Boot mapper with generic Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto

I am trying to make generic architecture with **Java framework Spring Boot**.

The mappers I tried doesn't seem to have a generic method like *Automapper* in .Net Core framework has -> `Mapper.Map<TEntity>(source)`.

> Is there a way to achieve in Spring Boot generic mapping without passing a target? Because my target is `TEntity` and it couldn't be directly instantiated (`T target = new T();`) to pass it directly in method (`mapper.map(source, target)`).

There is an example what I want to achieve in C# in .Net Core framework in Service layer.

```
public virtual TDataTransferObject Insert(TInsertDTO request){
   var entity = Mapper.Map<TEntity>(request);
   return Mapper.Map<TDataTransferObject>(Repository.Add(entity));
}
```

Comment: like [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)?

Answer (score 1):

My experience is mostly with [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) and it maps only between two objects or from an object to a target class.

On a quick glance over other popular [mappers](https://amydegregorio.com/2019/01/18/bean-mapping-alternatives-to-modelmapper/), they offer similar functionality in that regard, probably because of the [Type erasure](https://stackify.com/jvm-generics-type-erasure/) in Java.

To work around that limitation, type of the generic class should be added as a field to the base class. 
One solution is to pass it as argument to the base class' constructor.
Another is to use reflection:

```java
public abstract class BaseService<E> {

    private final Class<E> entityClass;
    private final ModelMapper mapper;

    protected BaseService(ModelMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        entityClass = getEntityClass();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Class<E> getEntityClass() {
        return (Class<E>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
           .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public <I, O> O insert(I inputData, Class<O> outClass) {
        E entity = mapper.map(inputData, entityClass);
        O outData = mapper.map(entity, outClass);
        return outData;
    }
}


public class FooService extends BaseService<Foo> {

    public FooService(ModelMapper mapper) {
        super(mapper);
    }
}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooService service = new FooService(new ModelMapper());

        Foo foo = new Foo("foo");
        Baz baz = service.insert(foo, Baz.class);
    }
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/1HRn)

An article comparing [Performance of Java Mapping Frameworks](https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts, but I've got instant error while trying to initialize **entityClass** in constructor. It doesn't let me to cast the type argument to `Class<E>`. 

Btw. this is my BaseService `public class BaseService<TEntity, TDto, IdType> implements IBaseService<TEntity, TDto, IdType> { ... }`

Comment: @Adnan Please show the code and the exact error it produces. You're not using`Class<E>` for a `BaseRntity<TEntity, ...>` class, don't you (it should be `Class<TEntity>`)? BTW, here's a simple [project](https://github.com/Martin-BG/SoftUni-Java-Web-Development-Basics-Jan-2019/blob/master/12.%20Exam/Final%20Exam/src/main/java/org/softuni/exam/services/BaseService.java) of mine where this concept is used.

Comment: Yes ofc I'm using `Class<TEntity>`, here is link to [code](https://github.com/AdnanIT/mDoc/tree/master/src/main/java/com/adnan/mDoc). I will take look on your project. Btw. don't mind if you find sth weird, it's my first Spring Boot test project, that's probably because there is lack of good Spring Boot demos and docs.

Comment: @Adnan I've checked your project's repository, but I'm afraid there are more serious problems there. I would recommend you to read a bit more on generics in Java. For example `public class CrudService<TEntity, TDto, Type, TUpdate, TInsert> extends BaseService<TEntity, TDto, Type> implements ICrudService<TEntity, TDto, Type, TUpdate, TInsert>` should be something like `public class CrudService extends BaseService<Country, CountryDTO, Long>` to allow Spring to create this bean.